# Pass response back to android but getting a nullPointerException in servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets

I have an android android app where im updating a product table by passing variables to the servlet. it updates the table but the problem is responding back to android. in the servlet im getting a nullpointerexception when trying to pass back a response to android. cant seem to understand why i am getting this, any help please :)

```
     else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase(("addProduct"))) {

            //update code runs here and it is successfull

            if(optionmobile.equalsIgnoreCase("mobileaddproduct")){

                if(merchID != null){

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject("executed");                        
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();       
               //if the merch != null; how do you stop the program here!
            }else{

                response.setContentType("text/html");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeObject("faliedToUpload");                    
                oos.flush();
                oos.close();

            }

        }else{                   
            session.setAttribute("testing", u);
            address = "test.jsp";
            }
            //my guess it breaks here after it runs the first condition.
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);       

        }
```

this is a java web application so thats why i have if(optionmobile.equalsIgnoreCase("mobileaddproduct")){ so to know the  request is coming from mobile!

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[MerchantController]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for     servlet MerchantController threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gobetween.merchant.MerchantController.processRequest(MerchantController.java:337)
at com.gobetween.merchant.MerchantController.doPost(MerchantController.java:374)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception? It indicates precisely where the exception is thrown.

Comment: As @JBNizet suggests, you need to look at the stack trace - if you don't understand it, post it in an edit to your question. You've only shown a snippet of code so it's impossible to tell.

Comment: stack trace:  Dont really understand this....

Comment: You just posted it. Now read it. The error occurs in the method processRequest() of the class MerchantController, at line 337 in the file MerchantController.java. Which is this line?

Comment: dispatcher.forward(request, response); is line 337! when i add product in website, dispatcher will forward the address to test.jsp. but since the request is coming from the app and response going to the app, how do you stop it from reaching the dispatcher(which is only used for the website). sorry man, bit a newbie to programming.

Comment: It makes no sense to dispatch to a JSP if you already sent something to the response and closed its stream. Only execute the request dispatching when it makes sense to do so (inside the last else block, for example).